# Dúvida sobre switch

Tags: c, switch, controle-de-fluxo

Gostaria que o `switch` me mostrasse a soma caso eu escolha `case 1` conforme segue o código, porém ele não efetua as operações.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

int a,b;
int operacao;
int soma = a + b;
int subtracao = a - b;
int multiplicacao = a * b;
int divisao = a / b;
//exponenciacao;


printf("digite o primeiro numero:\n");
scanf("%d", &a);
printf("digite o segundo numero:\n");
scanf("%d", &b);

printf("Qual operacao voce deseja ?\n");
printf(" 1 Soma\n 2 Subtracao\n 3 Multiplicacao\n 4 Divisao\n");
scanf("%d", &operacao);

switch(operacao)
{
case 1:
    printf("voce escolheu soma %d", soma);  *// AQUI EU GOSTARIA QUE ELE REALIZASSE A SOMA, PORÉM ELE SEMPRE APRESENTA O VALOR 10557854* 
    break;
case 2:
    printf("voce escolheu Subtracao %d", subtracao);
    break;
case 3:
    printf("voce escolheu Multiplicacao %d", multiplicacao);
    break;
case 4:
    printf("voce escolheu Divisao %d", divisao);
    break;

}
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Não sei porque criou essas variáveis, ainda mais fazendo as operações antes de ter os valores digitados. Um programa executa em uma ordem. E ao contrário do que deve ter aprendido, você declara as variáveis conforme a necessidade, no local mais próximo do seu uso.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b, operacao;
    printf("digite o primeiro numero:\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("digite o segundo numero:\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("Qual operacao voce deseja ?\n");
    printf(" 1 Soma\n 2 Subtracao\n 3 Multiplicacao\n 4 Divisao\n");
    scanf("%d", &operacao);
    switch (operacao) {
    case 1:
        printf("voce escolheu soma %d", a + b);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("voce escolheu Subtracao %d", a - b);
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("voce escolheu Multiplicacao %d", a * b);
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("voce escolheu Divisao %d", a / b);
        break;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/t8tJz5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/MathOperation). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/MathOperationOrder.c).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

As operações devem ser feitas depois que recebe os valores das variaveis.

```
case 1:
    printf("voce escolheu soma %d", a + b);
    break;
```

Ou

```
case 1:
    soma = a + b;
    printf("voce escolheu soma %d", soma);
    break;
```

Seu erro está sendo realizar a soma antes de ter os valores de a e b.

Comment: No caso então eu sempre tenho que chamar a operação dentro de cada case ? porque em cima no código tem uma parte que pede para o usuario digitar os valores de a e b e os mesmos sao atribuidos ás devidas variáveis e na declação da váriavel soma eu ja determinei que ela recebe o valor de a + b, pelo que entendi então eu devo "repetir" esse processo de declaração dentro de cada case, correto ?

Comment: Não precisa ser dentro do case, mas quando for realizar a operação as variaveis tem que ter valores. 
se você fizer assim:

int a = 10;
int b= 20;
int soma a +b; // vai dar 30

Mas se fizer:

int a;
int b;
int soma a +b; // vai dar problema, o programa não sabe os valores de a nem de b, como que ele vai somar valores que ele ainda desconhece? Quando o programa passa por uma linha ele executa a operação.

Comment: Agora entendi cara, esqueci do básico dele ler as instruções sequencialmente, muito obrigado pela ajuda.